# sheet.getLastRow() not working when launched by trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

A short description of the issue:

When running an automatic script with trigger head timebased the script failed
With the following error description

> Exception: The starting row of the range is too small. at fetchData(wkapi2:4:20)

(which means that the sheet is empty) and this is not the case the sheet has 300 rows.
It worked well until 2 days ago....I did not change the script nor any settings

**When I run the script manually, then everything works fine...**

The line of code is as follows :

```
function fetchData() {
  var options = {'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0, must-revalidate'}; //I've used this before to try and prevent google from giving me cached data when making API calls..seems to get the job done
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //This script is bound to the corresponding sheet so we can use this conveinience method
  var cell = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1); //Get a reference to current last cell in Column A
```

The scripts Fails at the
`sheet.getRange (... )`  function when automatically run

When I run manually it works

Comment: If the sheet is not empty - you must be retrieving the wrong active sheet on trigger. Can you provide some background on your sheet, trigger and maybe additional relevant code parts that you missed out? What is the purpose of `options`?

Answer (score 2):

When run without a "active" spreadsheet, (i.e., a spreadsheet that  is visible in the browser), "active" sheet would refer to the first sheet. Use `Spreadsheet.getSheetByName()` instead of `getActiveSheet()`.